# Running jquery action through a link from another site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 2 sites, the first site and the second site named SiteA named SiteB. SiteA has links I want those links that when clicked it will execute action in SiteB jquery.

SiteA links:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg start-vendor" href="#modal"><i class="fa fa-gift"></i>Apa yang akan Anda dapatkan?</a>
```

SiteB has 2 `<div>`:

1.

```
<div id="user-page" class="fitures"> 
<! - Some of the content -> 
</ div>
```

2.

```
<div id="vendor-page" class="fitures" style="display:none;"> 
<! - Some of the content -> 
</ div>
```

I have a jquery action in SiteB:

```
$('.start-vendor').click(function() {
    $("#vendor-page").fadeIn().show();
    $("#user-page").fadeOut().hide();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#one-vendor").offset().top+10
    }, 2000, function() {
});
return false;
});
```

When the link (above) in SiteA with the class `second` clicked it will go to SiteB and run action `<div id="user-page">` jquery to hide then show `<div id="user-page">`

is that possible? and what's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with hash in the URL.

if you want the user-page to be open so send the user to:

www.mysite.com/#user-page

And then in site B read the hash with JS:

```
window.location.hash
```

And open the one that you want.